# pyspark piplineRDD fit to Dataframe column

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Before everything i'm new guy in python and spark world.
I have homework from university but i stuck in one place.
I make clusterization from my data and now i have my clusters in PipelinedRDD

aftre this:
`cluster = featurizedScaledRDD.map(lambda r: kmeansModelMllib.predict(r))
cluster  = [2,1,2,0,0,0,1,2]`

now now i have `cluster` and my dataframe `dataDf` i need fit my `cluster` like a new column to `dataDf`

```
    i Have:               i Need:
    +---+---+---+        +---+---+---+-------+
    | x | y | z |        | x | y | z |cluster|
    +---+---+---+        +---+---+---+-------+
    | 0 | 1 | 1 |        | 0 | 1 | 1 |   2   |
    | 0 | 0 | 1 |        | 0 | 0 | 1 |   1   |
    | 0 | 8 | 0 |        | 0 | 8 | 0 |   2   |
    | 0 | 8 | 0 |        | 0 | 8 | 0 |   0   |
    | 0 | 1 | 0 |        | 0 | 1 | 0 |   0   |
    +---+---+---+        +---+---+---+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add index using `zipWithIndex`, `join`, and convert back to `df`.

```
swp = lambda x: (x[1], x[0])

cluster.zipWithIndex().map(swp).join(dataDf.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(swp)) \ 
  .values().toDF(["cluster", "point"])
```

In some cases it should be possible to use `zip`:

```
cluster.zip(dataDf.rdd).toDF(["cluster", "point"])
```

You can follow with `.select("cluster", "point.*")` to flatten the output.

Comment: I think I might have edit it after you've seen it for the first time.